# Enhance database table with custom record ordering per date

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Think of the current `VISITS` table:

```
ID   ID_PERSON  DATE
1    1          10/12/2012
2    5          10/12/2012
3    11         10/12/2012
4    55         10/13/2012
5    12         10/13/2012
6    6          10/14/2012
7    10         10/15/2012
8    13         10/15/2012
9    11         10/15/2012
10   5          10/16/2012
```

What I need is to create custom ordering of the visits *per day*:

Order **1, 2, 3** for date **10/12/2012**, **1,2** for date **10/13/2012** etc.

At first it can be random, but then the user can create the order, which is not of my concern at this point.

What would be the SQL command to add a random ordering column to this table?

Possible result:

```
ID   ID_PERSON  DATE         ORDER_IN_DATE
1    1          10/12/2012   2
2    5          10/12/2012   3
3    11         10/12/2012   1
4    55         10/13/2012   1
5    12         10/13/2012   1
6    6          10/14/2012   1
7    10         10/15/2012   1
8    13         10/15/2012   3
9    11         10/15/2012   2
10   5          10/16/2012   1
```

Ordering rules: Random when first creating the `ORDER_BY_DATE` column. (Of course auto increased value counts as random as well).

SOLUTION:
**a.** Update table `VISIT` to add `ORDER_IN_DATE` column, **b.** Execute the following query:

```
UPDATE VISIT
SET ORDER_IN_DATE = (SELECT TEMP_ORDER 
                     FROM (SELECT  V.ID AS TEMP_ID, 1 + ROWID % (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                                 FROM VISIT
                                                                 WHERE DATE = V.DATE
                                                                ) AS TEMP_ORDER
                           FROM VISIT V
                           ORDER BY DATE, RANDOM())
                     WHERE ID = TEMP_ID);
```

Comment: It is not clear what output order do you want. Can you give an example of what result should look like and what is your sorting criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you want to sort by date first, and then randomize visits within date.

In that case, this should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM visits
ORDER BY date, random()
```

**EDIT**:

Use this if you want to save order within date as an additional column `order_in_date`:

```
SELECT *,
    1 + rowid % (
        SELECT count(*) FROM visits
        WHERE date = v.date
    ) AS order_in_date
FROM visits v
ORDER BY date, random()
```

Comment: I want the order to be saved.

Comment: Does it have to be 100% SQL? It is easy to save order generated by `random()` using some script (Perl, PHP, etc)

Comment: Yes, because it's a schema update and it must not be done with code.

Comment: I have checked it thoroughly - works great on your example. Are you sure that it does not work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice the difference of the date year.